# Phoenix + ExMachina error

Tags: web, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following along [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/mixology-exmachina-92a08dc3e954#.3bfb2l6nf) and after adding [this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.cm/Diamond/adbc87f74d76d2c74694/raw/77c4709f9455bf41bd7a8a0c2caf4951859eee09/mix1_fig2.exs) and a role Factory, I'm getting the following errors:

> 15:09:08.808 [error] GenServer #PID<0.245.0> terminating
>   ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Adapters.SQL.begin_test_transaction/1 is undefined or private.
>   Did you mean one of:
>
> ```
>   * in_transaction?/1
>
> (ecto) Ecto.Adapters.SQL.begin_test_transaction(Pxblog.Repo)
> (elixir) src/elixir_compiler.erl:125: :elixir_compiler.dispatch_loaded/6
> (elixir) src/elixir_lexical.erl:17: :elixir_lexical.run/3
> (elixir) src/elixir_compiler.erl:30: :elixir_compiler.quoted/3
> (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
> (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
> (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum.each/2
> (mix) lib/mix/tasks/test.ex:216: Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1
> ```

Here it is my **test_helper.exs** file:

```
{:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:ex_machina)
ExUnit.start

Mix.Task.run "ecto.create", ~w(-r Pxblog.Repo --quiet)
Mix.Task.run "ecto.migrate", ~w(-r Pxblog.Repo --quiet)
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.begin_test_transaction(Pxblog.Repo)
```

What could be wrong? I already updated all the dependencies with **`mix deps.update --all`**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to follow tutorial targeting Ecto 1.1 having installed Ecto 2.0, that is not fully backwards compatible. You can either downgrade your ecto version, look for an updated tutorial or explore the changes in Ecto 2, and adapt the tutorial you're currently using - http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/ecto-2-0-0-rc-is-out/ should give you a good start.